# Texto do Toast fora de alinhamento

Tags: android

Estou trabalhando em um pequeno projeto para a faculdade e me deparei com isso ao utilizar um toast:
[image: Toast Bizarro]

Não faço ideia do que fez o toast ficar assim. Alguém já passou por algum problema semelhante?

Edição:
Esse é o código que estou usando para criar o Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(Singleton.getInstance().getContext(), "Nota criada com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Percebi que o erro apareceu após eu ter instalado a biblioteca SystemBarTint. Antes de usá-la, eu havia tentado obter o mesmo resultado usando apenas aquivos XML, mas não fiquei satisfeito. Será que algo nisso pode estar influenciando? Esse é o meu `styles.xml` atual:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Notas.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Notas.ActionBar.OverflowMenu</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Notas.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/roxo</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Notas.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Notas.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/branco</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Notas.ActionBar.OverflowMenu" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">
            @android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown
        </item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Poderia incluir o código? Será que não é nenhuma quebra de linha que força o texto a ter duas linhas? Poderia testar um `trim` na `String`?

Comment: @Wakim, editei a minha pergunta. Vou testar o trim agora. EDIT: o `trim` não resolveu o problema.

Comment: Olhando o código não tem nenhum erro. O `trim` não vai adiantar. Deve ser algum estilo que está influenciando no Toast, tem que verificar o `style` dele. Eu não recomendo colocar o `fitSystemWindows` e o `clipToPadding` no `AppTheme`, podem interferir em muita coisa. Eu em geral coloco em cada `View` raiz do layout, mas pode ser trabalhoso. Tente fazer o seguinte: remova esses dois atributos pra ver se são eles que estão causando problema no `Toast`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o atributo `android:fitsSystemWindows` é específico para declarações de `View's` em layout xml, não para temas.

Se deseja manter o tema com esse atributo, um "*workaround*" seria usar o `getApplicationContext()` ou `getApplication()`, como contexto para o `makeText`. Dessa forma:

```
// Se estiver dentro de uma Activity
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nota criada com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// ou

Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nota criada com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

O ideal é mover o atributo `android:fitsSystemWindows` para cada `View` que é a raiz dos seus layouts.

Mais informações: [Android AOSP Issue 63653](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63653).